# Alfresco community 4.0.d on Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: glassfish, alfresco

When I try to install alfresco community 4.0.d on Glassfish 3.1.1 I get the following installation error:

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: class org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.webservices.AuthHandler does not implement one of the handler interfaces.. Please see server.log for more details.

Please help as I am stuck on this one.................

Comment: Did you try following the instructions on the [Alfresco on Glassfish wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_on_Glassfish)?

Answer (score 1):

I did not yet try alfresco on glassfish myself, but the issue pretty much looks like a classloading problem to me.

I don't know exactly what the handler interfaces are, but I guess you have the corresponding .class files in the webapp and in the server as well. If that proves to be the case, you can try removing them in one location and see if that helps getting the system to work.

But to be honest, I would suggest you use the system as it is shipping with tomcat bundled, unless you have a very good reason to use a "less supported" environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a glassfish-web.xml to the WEB-INF folder of the the alfresco.war with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```